# T-SQL How to copy data from table with parameterized name to temporary table

Tags: sql-server

My procedure has two parameters:
@schemaName as sysname
@tableName as sysname
Inside the procedure, I want to copy data from table schemaName.tableName to the new temporary table # tmpTable1 .
My default schema in the database is schemaX, not dbo and I am not the dbo user.

```
Create procedure copy_data_to_temp
   @schemaName as sysname,
   @tableName as sysname
AS
Begin
Exec('select * into #tmpTable1 from ' + @schemaName  + '.' + @tableName)
Select * from #tmpTable1 – does not work, because after dynamic SQL #tmpTable1 does not  exist
END
I have tried:
-- Exec('Select * into Tdummy from ' + @schemaName  + ’.’ + @tableName + ' where 1=2'’)
-- Select * into  #tmpTable1 from Tdummy  -- Gives error: Invalid object name 'Tdummy', when I am not dbo user and my default schema is schemaX not dbo.
-- Exec('Insert into #tmpTable1 select *  from '+ @schemaName  + '.' + @tableName)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 problems here. Firstly, what you have is **dangerously** open to Injection. That **must** be fixed. I cannot stress that more than anything in this answer. If you learn nothing else from this, learn to write **secure** dynamic statements.

Secondly, temporary objects only persist for the duration of the scope you define them in. For the above, that's the duration of the dynamic statement, and that is it.

This, however, has a strong "code smell" of being an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) but I'll go on to answering this anyway.

You'll need to create a persisted object and then `SELECT` from that in the procedure, and then "clean up":

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.copy_data_to_temp @SchemaName sysname, @TableName sysname AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.tmpTable;

    SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO tempdb.dbo.tmpTable FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N';'
    FROM sys.schemas s
         JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
    WHERE s.name = @SchemaName
      AND t.[name] = @TableName;

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

    SELECT *
    FROM tempdb.dbo.tmpTable;

    --DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.tmpTable;

END;
```

Of course, the `SELECT ... INTO tmpTable ... FROM {dynamic object}` followed by the `SELECT ... FROM tmpTable` might as well just be a `SELECT ... FROM {dynamic object}`, and why this looks like a XY Problem.

---

When using Dynamic SQL, you need to make sure you use it properly and safely. Rather than repeating myself, you can learn a lot from my article [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).

Comment: Thank You. I want to copy data to „real”  temporary table, with the sign ‘#’ at the beginig of a name.Your solution writes data to a persistent table in tempdb database, and that's not the point.
I am aware of the injection problem, but in question I just simplified the code.

Comment: @Miroslaw I explain that in the answer... *"temporary objects only persist for the duration of the scope you define them in"*

Answer (score 1):

Declare the **#temp** table before using `exec` and then also add `INSERT INTO`

```
create table #temp
(
...
)

insert into #temp
Exec (...)

-- return results from exec
Select * from #temp
```

Comment: This does assume that the (dynamic) table will always have the same definition; which could very easily be a flawed assumption.

Comment: @Larnu cant that easily be over come by explicitly using certain columns in the `select` statement. I was lazy and used */... Because example data was not provided so I don't know what columns are available anyways.

Comment: Considering that the OP uses `*`, that suggests they want all the columns, not just *some* of them.

Comment: I, do, however, strongly suggest at least convering the severe injection problem the OP has. Leaving it in situ is pure negligence in my own opinion. SQL Injection vulnerabilities *should* have been eradicated years ago.

Comment: Yep you could explicitly list out every column in the `select` statement which would guanteed keep both in sync. Only downside is if a new column is added the temp table declaration and the select both have to be manually updated, this is not dynamic.

Comment: @Larnu. Thank You. I want to copy data to „real”  temporary table, with the sign ‘#’ at the beginig of a name.Your solution writes data to a persistent table in tempdb database, and that's not the point.
I am aware of the injection problem, but in question I just simplified the code.
 I would like to understand why error  Invalid object name 'Tdummy' occurs, when I am not dbo user and my default schema is schemaX not dbo (see commented code in my question).

Comment: @Miroslaw I explain that ***in*** the answer... From *my* answer: *"temporary objects only persist for the duration of the scope you define them in"*